# How do I run a single nosetest via setup.py in the python-active-directory module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, nose, setup.py

I am stubbornly trying to convert the Python module https://github.com/theatlantic/python-active-directory to Python 3.  You can see my efforts here https://github.com/nbmorgan/python-active-directory/tree/master3.

I have figured out the following things, I can run the test suite within the cloned project by either:

1. `export TEST_CONF_NAME="test.conf" ; python setup.py test`
   or
2. `export TEST_CONF_NAME="../test.conf" ; python setup.py nosetests`

This creates a huge output with the first simple test at the top. I have tried to use several forms of the run single test variations described in the help for setup or nosetest, but I'm usually met with `module not found` errors or some variant of `test not defined`.

If someone could point me at the command line that would let me run just: `test_client.TestADClient.test_domains` that would be awesome.

For now I am using: `export TEST_CONF_NAME="../test.conf" ; python setup.py nosetests 2>&1 | cat -n | head -80 | tail -31` which is cheesy, but gets me the information.

I would like to thank the author for having tests - which makes a cold approach to a refactor possible. I am not a Python module builder, just a module user trying to help.

Comment: Mythical Bonus Points (MBP) for showing how to launch a test with debugger + pycharm

Comment: Just FYI.. are you aware that they merged a PR adding Python 3 support only a week ago: https://github.com/theatlantic/python-active-directory/pull/1

Comment: I back burnered this.  Thanks for the info.  I still want to drive this question so that people that know enough to be dangerous but are not familiar with pytest / nose can run tests in modules.

Answer (score 1):

Is running using `setup` a requirement? I run certain test like this:

```
nosetests tests/core/test_client.py:TestADClient.test_search --collect
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
OK
```

But actual run fails because tests use pytest fixture (conf argument for tests). So you need to run it using pytest.

```
$ pytest tests/core/test_client.py::TestADClient::test_search -vv
============================ test session starts ============
...
collected 1 item                                                             
tests/core/test_client.py::TestADClient::test_search SKIPPED                           [100%]
```

Comment: No requirement to run setup.  It was the only path that did anything function for me. 

Where are you standing (pwd) in the tree when you run the pytest command?

Comment: In root folder of the repo - `ls -> ... setup.cfg setup.py tests ...`

Answer (score 0):

looks like a duplicate of :

[How to run unit tests with "pip install"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055422/how-to-run-unit-tests-with-pip-install/55539981#55539981)  which I answered some time ago.

however - `setup.py test` is deprecated, so i would not use it for a new development.

look at : https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#test-build-package-and-run-a-unittest-suite

therefore, for new projects I would suggest the use of a makefile.

```
make install
make test
make clean 
# etc ...
```